# Ajax not working in Chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a sample extension, this is how it should work. My extension has an option page, when people click on the sign-in button, it sends an ajax request to test.php and gets information to alert user. But it does not work, I don't know why. 
this is my folder structure

```
chrome 

  \ manifest.json
  \ options.html
  \ options.js
  \ test.php
```

in options.html

```
<div class="login-button" id="login-button">Sign in</div>
```

in options.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    alert('hello');
    $('#login-button').click(function() {
        loginAjax();
    });
 })
 function loginAjax() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'test.php',
       data: "",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
       }
    });
 }
```

In the Ajax URL I tried to put an absolute path, but it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: It already work, i don't know:-D**

Comment: i know but i don't know how to show my code:((

Comment: you have a few options ... directly, [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/#javascript,html,live) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and probably others ... and simply putting .. "it does not work" doesnt help anyone - perhaps include the error message you receive in your debugger ...

Comment: `test.php` where it is located? I mean can you give the full path

Comment: i already update my question:)

Comment: @MQuy : Please "accept" your previous 3 questions.

Comment: Chrome is not capable of executing PHP scripts. You have to use an absolute URL if you want to request a PHP file from some server. Also, access to this file must be enabled by adding the URL to the permissions field in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest instead of jquery
see more http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html